# Rspec2: Mock class methods, but not all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I've wrote a  class method, which calls other class methods of the same class.

```
class Statistic
  def self.do_something
    #...
  end

  def self.update_statistic
    Statistic.do_something
  end
end
```

How do I test, that update_statistic calls do_something?

I use Rails 3 & rspec 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to set an expectation on `do_something` and then call `update_statistic` directly.

```
Statistic.should_receive(:do_something)
Statistic.update_statistic
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know, that should_receive is available on every object.